# How can I access data of object stored in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, object

I would like to get data of an object stored in an array. But I don't know how :/

Here the class type of my object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Account : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *accountNumber;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *accountName;

@end


Account *model = [[Account alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CELL; i++){

        [model setAccountName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account %d",i]];
        [model setAccountNumber:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number %d",i]];

        [_accountArray addObject:model];

    }
```

I list this in a UITableView:

```
cell.accountLabel.text = ?
```

Thanks you for you help!
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong. Account Object is created only once. So that you are see only one object.

use below code.

```
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CELL; i++){

    Account *model = [[Account alloc]init];

    [model setAccountName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account %d",i]];
    [model setAccountNumber:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number %d",i]];

    [_accountArray addObject:model];

}
```

and to display data use below code :

```
Account *model = [_accountArray objectatIndex:indexpath.row];
cell.accountLabel.text = model.accountName;
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Comment: I tried this way but I have only the last value of my array. The initializing of my array is in the method: viewDidLoad.

Comment: where you alloc _accountArray?

Comment: it should be look like this : NSMutableArray *_accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CELL; i++){
        
        [model setAccountName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account %d",i]];
        [model setAccountNumber:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number %d",i]];
        
        [_accountArray addObject:model];
        
    }

Comment: Can you please +1 answer? Thanks :)

Comment: I have no reputation enough :'( At least 15 ans I have only 3 ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
Account *model = [_accountArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.accountLabel.text = model. setAccountName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be acheived using the following code

```
Account *model = [_accountArray objectatIndex:indexpath.row];
cell.accountLabel.text = model. AccountName;
```